# REST endpoint returns different results in AWS vs. localhost

Tags: java, spring, rest, amazon-web-services

**EDIT:** It looks like my observation that both localhost and AWS were returning 409 was incorrect. AWS is returning 500 (which I would still expect to return null, as the @ExceptionHandler method for Exception.class clearly sets the status to 500 and returns null). Looking closer at the exception message, "could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode", this is looking more like a database-issue.

**ORIGINAL:**

I have a RESTful service written in Java/Spring. In this service, I have 3 @ExceptionHandler methods, *all of which return null*. Only one exception sets the status to 409 Conflict, which is the one I'm expecting in my current scenario.

While testing the service with Postman on localhost, under a particular circumstance, I get an expected 409 Conflict with **no data body**. However, when I hit the service after being deployed on amazonaws.com, I get the 409 Conflict with a **result body consisting of timestamp, status, error, exception, and message** values. The version returned by /manage/info looks correct and the git commit data is reported exactly the same.

The localhost version returns 4 headers (plus a custom one):

- Content-Length = 0
- Date = (today)
- Server = Apache-Coyote/1.1
- X-Application-Context = application

The Amazon AWS version returns 5 headers (plus the same custom one):

- Content-Type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
- Date = (today)
- Server = Apache-Coyote/1.1
- Transfer-Encoding = chunked
- X-Application-Content = application, application

What could be causing this? My application calling the service ~could~ handle either situation, but it seems wrong to bandage a fix there when obviously something weird is going on in the service, itself. It was coded to expect null, not a body consisting of values that would not be part of a non-409 result.

Comment: YIKES! Looks like I overlooked something. The response coming back from the AWS server is NOT a 409 as I originally said, but a 500. I suspect this question may be off. I am updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

> What could be causing this?

It is most likely the web-app framework that you are using to run the service.  It might be an inherent difference in framework software (on your local machine and AWS), or there could be configuration differences.

(I note that you haven't mentioned *how* you are running the service locally.)

> My application calling the service ~could~ handle either situation, but it seems wrong to bandage a fix there when obviously something weird is going on in the service, itself. It was coded to expect null, not a body consisting of values that would not be part of a non-409 result.

I disagree that there is "obviously something weird" going on.  This is the sort of thing that >>I<< would expect if I tried to run a web service on a range of different web platforms.  Especially if I was taking a "light touch" approach to configuration / deployment.

You could probably make your local host platform handle error responses more like AWS, and possibly the other way around.

But I think the simple solution is to change the client to work with both kinds of error response.

---

I think my answer still applies to your updated question.  Modify your client code to handle error responses with and without bodies.  It is also worth logging the response body for *unexpected* responses.

Comment: I'm running locally via Eclipse, as a Spring Boot App.